# Why the LSTM model is not predicting the values properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am using an LSTM model to predict data. But when the model executes, it doesn't wrap to the values at the edges.

[Graphed Result * CLICK to VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9QsX.png)

and here is the lstm model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in,1))))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_steps_out))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mae", metrics = [test_acc])

# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=7)
```

Can someone explain why the model doesn't predict the values till the bottom, 0r at least get close to it?

P.S : I have tried changing the epoch to 100 and other combinations also

Comment: I have not implemented a seed yet, so the values do vary a bit but the model doesn't seem to be able to predict the values to the bottom.